# Linq to XML - set Xelement value depending on if Statement

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I'm Creating an xml using linq to xml.

In one element i'd like to control the value of the element depending on a statement

```
<Type>Query</Type>
```

"Query" depends on a few variables in an object, so i have to run 1-2 if statements.
(This is a part of a big xml being written)
I know what i'm writing is not possible this way, i'm looking for a way to do this in any legal way possible

```
new XElement("Parameters",
from p in parameters.ParametersList
select
    new XElement("Parameter", 
        new XAttribute("ID", "??"),
        new XAttribute("Name", p.Name),
        new XElement("Prompt", p.Prompt),
        if (p.validvalues.count == 0)
            new XElement("Type", "None")
        else if (p.something == something)
               new XElement("Type, "List")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ternary operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) (?:):

```
new XElement("Type", (p.validvalues.Count() == 0) ? "None" : "List")
```

If you have complex conditions or many possible values, you can extract method for getting this node value:

```
new XElement("Type", GetParameterType(p))
```

And

```
private string GetParameterType(Parameter p)
{
    if (p.validvalues.Count() == 0)
        return "None";

    if (p.something == something)
        return "List";

    // etc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think nothing prevents you to insert a method into XElement constructor and add a logic that is suitable for you.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var parameters = new List<MyParam> { 
            new MyParam { Name="bla", Size=1 }, 
            new MyParam { Name="lala", Size=10 }, 
        };

        var xml = new XElement("Parameters",
            from p in parameters
            select new XElement("Parameter",
                 new XAttribute("Name", p.Name),
                 ConditionalElement(p)
                )
        );
    }

    private static XElement ConditionalElement(MyParam arg)
    {
        if (arg.Size < 5)
        {
            return new XElement("Type", "Small");
        }
        else
        {
            return new XElement("Type", "Big");
        }
    }

}

class MyParam
{
    public int Size { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This is also a good solution for me, but it's a simple "if" i had to write so i went with ternary operator